# Двойная проверка цикла, разной длинны .length

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 массива, первый имеет в себе префиксы, и его длинна: 2, второй уже имеет в себе 10-15 элементов, и его length 10-15 примерно, мне нужно делать проверку если введён один из префиксов из массива "A" и массива "B", но писать так:

```
const prefixes = ['1', '2'];
const context = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8];
for(i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
 for(k = 0; k < context.length; k++) {
  if(msg.txt == `${prefixes[i]} ${context[k]}`) return true;
 }
}
```

Не вариант для меня, сами понимаете что такой код даже визуально выглядить неправильно, скажите пожалуйста, как правильно нужно писать в подобных ситуациях

```
var msg = prompt();
msg = msg.trim()
var arr_l = ['!к', '.к'];
var arr_r = ['1', '2', '3'];


for(i = 0; i < arr_l.length; i++) {
    if(msg == `${arr_l[i]} ${arr_r[i]}`) console.log(true)
    else console.warn(false);
}

/*
    Не сработает так-как если ввести "!к 3", он попросту не найдет его, так-как индекс i = 2 (его максимум)
*/
```

Сработало так:

```
var msg = prompt();
var arr_l = ['!к', '.к'];
var arr_r = ['1', '2', '3'];

var parts = msg.split(' ');
if (arr_l.includes(parts[0]) && arr_r.includes(parts[1])) {
    console.log(true)
    console.log(msg)
} else {
    console.warn(false);
}
```

(Комментарий ниже)

Comment: сравнение в if проводится знаком == , а у вас присвоение.
`if(msg.txt == `${prefixes[i]} ${context[k]}`) return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы сделал так:

1. разбить строку через разделитель (пробел) на 2 части
2. проверить, есть ли первая часть в массиве 1
3. проверить, есть ли вторая часть в массиве 2

Вам такой код нужен?

```
const arr_l = ['!k', '.k'];
const arr_r = ['1', '2', '3'];

const parts = msg.split(' ');

if (arr_l.includes(parts[0]) && arr_r.includes(parts[0]))
    return true;
```

Comment: тут дело в том, что мне нужно проверять оба массива одновременно, если быть точнее, то первый массив всегда должен проходить проверку, то-есть, есть ли текст из 0-1 индекса массива в msg.txt. Так-как в массиве всего 2 индекса, то массив в котором их больше, не пройдет проверку полностью

Comment: @Алис Королев, может я не понял вопроса - приложил к своему ответу еще и код - вам такое нужно?

Comment: о, это правда то что нужно, однако, я ни разу не слышал о "includes", пожалуй пойду почитаю об этом

Comment: погоди, это конечно сработало, но лишь с цифрами, я сейчас немного посмотрел, и понял что он parseInt преобразует строки в числа, но мне нужно не это, мне нужно проверять в целом msg.txt на наличие определенного текста в ней

Comment: @Алис Королев, ну тогда массив сделать надо ['1', '2', '3'] и т.д., а `parseInt` убрать, и будет сравнение строк, т.е. надо сделать массивы строк, код тогда гораздо компактнее будет :)

Comment: я обновил вопрос, проверь код ниже (в самом посте)

Comment: @Алис Королев, посмотрел ваш код - так нельзя, обновил свой  - посмотрите его, можете в чат отдельно написать - обсудим 1 на 1 - так быстрее будет

Comment: помог такой вариант:

Comment: var msg = prompt();
var arr_l = ['!к', '.к'];
var arr_r = ['1', '2', '3'];

var parts = msg.split(' ');
if (arr_l.includes(parts[0]) && arr_r.includes(parts[1])) {
    console.log(true)
    console.log(msg)
} else {
    console.warn(false);
}